# AMSを用いたSMSの送信

Tags: php, cakephp, aws

AWSを用いて電話番号をサーバーに送信したユーザーにSMSでメッセージを送信したいと考えています。
しかし検索してみたりいろいろしてみたのですが、ヒットしません。

サーバーでの言語はPHPを使っていません。
おそらくAWSが提供しているSDK for PHPを用いて、
SNSの設定をするのではないかと考えています。
（参考：http://docs.amazonaws.cn/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html
）

どなたか以上のような設定したことがある方がいらっしゃいましたら、
参考にしたサイトなどを教えていただけますでしょうか。

なにかありましたら、随時補足致しますので
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sns/latest/dg/SMS-subscribe-to-topic.html
上記ドキュメントにて「SMS 通知は、現在、米国内の電話番号でサポートされています。」とありますが、対象は米国内の電話番号で間違いありませんか？

Comment: 私は、それは送信者の電話番号がアメリカのものであれば大丈夫だと理解していたつもりなのですが、もしかしてSMSの受信者も米国のものでなくてはいけないでしょうか。

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/jp/sns/faqs/の方がわかりやすいですね。受信側の登録が米国のみと明記されてます。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/24377 マルチポスト